# Installing Ubuntu 11.10 from LiveUSB

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install 11.10 on my computer to dual boot it with windows 7 and when I'm in the try Linux area and try to install Linux off of my liveusb I get to the point where its supposed to ask if i'd like to install it alongside windows 7, but it never shows that option it only shows the options to install over the entire hard drive and the advanced options one ie it never recognizes that I have anything else on my hard drive could someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Have you tried the advanced partition editor?

Comment: Check if you already have 4 primary partitions on your hard drive; If you do, either remove one or move them into extended partitions.

Comment: It wont even let me get to the advanced partition editor and according to the windows 7 disk manager I only have 3 partitions (windows backup, windows 7, and a partition that i made for ubuntu)

Comment: the advanced partition editor should be the last option labeled as "something else" where you should be able to edit the partition table. You'll need to kill that last partition you made for Ubuntu, and create a swap and allocate the rest to Ubuntu, meaning you should have two NTFS partitions, a SWAP and an ext4 for Ubuntu (make "/" the mounting point for the ext4 partition).

Answer (score 0):

Forget all these. Download Wubi and use the iso you already have to install Ubuntu. I dont think you need more than 30GB of installation space.

Here's how to install using Wubi.

```
 Log into windows.
 Create a new folder on desktop
 Download the Wubi installer and move the installer to "new folder"
 Copy and paste the Ubuntu ISO into the new folder.

 Double click on Wubi.exe to start the installation
 Give a password
```

Wait for the installation to complete.

Thats it.